# Setting false to bool property in react state does nothing

Tags: reactjs, object, boolean, state

Hello guys im having a little logic problem with one of my components, im currently using react-switch

```
        <Switch
            onChange={e => this.handleSwitch(e, 'spaces', 'living')}
            checked={this.state.dwelling.spaces.living === undefined ? true : this.state.dwelling.spaces.living}
            id="normal-switch"
            onColor="#86d3ff"
            onHandleColor="#2693e6"
            handleDiameter={20}
            uncheckedIcon={false}
            checkedIcon={false}
            boxShadow="0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)"
            activeBoxShadow="0px 0px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"
            height={15}
            width={38}
            className="react-switch"
        />
```

so in this first part im trying to set to default a true value for checked, then it comes the handler,

```
 handleSwitch(e, type, subtype) {
    this.setState(
        state => ({
            dwelling: {
                ...state.dwelling,
                [type]: {...state.dwelling[type], [subtype]: e}
            }
        })
    );
    console.log(this.state.dwelling.spaces);
}
```

for some reason on the frist click on the switch, my state object dosen't change but the switch goes in off state, 2nd click switch goes ON and the state in a value of FALSE 3rd click switch goes off and state in true value. I'm really confused about the results.

Comment: the console.log is not going to always give you the current state, instead if you add the console.log in your setState callback then it will work. What I mean is this:
```
this.setState(state => ({//do your thing}), () => console.log())
```

Comment: true my bad it was all about the console .log place it was working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `console.log` reads old values if it is outside of the `setState` - if you place it inside of that function, it works fine.

but why is that ?
Well, because [state updates might be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) (and react might even batch multiple batch updates), causing you to see the old state